# Djoser - Override registration

Tags: django-rest-framework, djoser

I'm confused as to how to modify the registration endpoint for Djoser. All I would like to do is add scoped throttling to the endpoint, but I can't understand how to override it.
This page on the docs talks about it: https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/adjustment.html
But it seems outdated?
How would it be done today with the UserViewSet & make sure the url works as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is to subclass djoser `UserViewSet` and add your extra code. Something like this should work

```
# your_views.py

from djoser.views import UserViewSet as DjoserUserViewSet


class UserViewSet(DjoserUserViewSet):

    def get_throttles(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            self.throttle_classes = [YourThrottleClass]
        return super().get_throttles()
```

And then in your `urls.py` you should NOT include `djoser.urls` in your `urlpatterns`

Instead of this (taken from their docs, you might have other url):

```
urlpatterns = [
    (...),
    url(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
]
```

Do this in your `urlpatterns` (you may already have a router defined):

```
# I have use endpoint "auth/users" to keep it similar to the above, but it can be just simple "users"

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("auth/users", your_views.UserViewSet)  

urlpatterns = [
    (...),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Behind the scene `djoser.urls` is registering `users` endpoint but with their internal `UserViewSet` so in this way you can use your own custom class.

Comment: This worked, I had to remove the quotes around router.urls though, e.g url(r'^', include(router.urls)). Also instead of adding a throttle class I was also able to add throttle_scope instead, using self.throttle_scope = "mycustomscope" instead of self.throttle_classses. Also using djoser_views.UserViewSet didn't work, I had to import the UserViewSet. Maybe you can edit your answer :)
Thank you! The way the router works when overriding & needing to call the super was the points I must have failed at previously.

Comment: I have edited the answer to fix the problems described.